# Xcode Error Instance Method -addAttachment withImageNamed not found

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, compiler-errors

I have got an error in my project, I'm getting Xcode Error Instance Method -addAttachment withImageNamed not found, Below is some of my code:

**HegakaDragAndDropRecycleBinViewController.h**

```
@interface HegakaDragAndDropRecycleBinViewController : UIViewController {
IBOutlet GalleryScrollView *gallery;

}
-(NSString*)withImageNamed;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet GalleryScrollView *gallery;
@end
```

**HegakaDragAndDropRecycleBinViewController.m**

```
#import "HegakaDragAndDropRecycleBinViewController.h"
#import "AttachmentItem.h"

@implementation HegakaDragAndDropRecycleBinViewController

@synthesize gallery;

- (void)dealloc
{
[super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
// Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

// Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
[super viewDidLoad];
self.gallery.mainView = self.view;


AttachmentItem *item = [[AttachmentItem alloc] initWithData:1 data:nil];
[self.gallery addAttachment:item withImageNamed:@"recyclebin"];
[self.gallery addAttachment:item withImageNamed:@"canadian-maple"];
[self.gallery addAttachment:item withImageNamed:@"light-cherry"];
[self.gallery addAttachment:item withImageNamed:@"mozambique-wenge"];
[self.gallery addAttachment:item withImageNamed:@"canadian-maple"];

[item release];
}

 - (void)viewDidUnload
 {
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
// Return YES for supported orientations
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

I'm getting my alert warning at the Implementation line and here:

```
[self.gallery addAttachment:item withImageNamed:@"recyclebin"];
[self.gallery addAttachment:item withImageNamed:@"canadian-maple"];
[self.gallery addAttachment:item withImageNamed:@"light-cherry"];
[self.gallery addAttachment:item withImageNamed:@"mozambique-wenge"];
[self.gallery addAttachment:item withImageNamed:@"canadian-maple"];
```

The project still runs but has this 6 warnings.

Any assistance is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your class `AttachmentItem` declares `addAttachment:withImageNamed:` in its header file

Answer (score 0):

First of all:

- What does the warning says?

What I think is happening is that you should import the GalleryScrollView in your .m file. Since you are trying to use a method from that specific class, I guess Xcode, is not able to see that it has  `-addAttachment:withImageNamed:`. That's why it runs ok (the method exists in fact), but gives a warning because from a `HegakaDragAndDropRecycleBinViewController` you can't see it. Also, you should [treat warnings as errors](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/xcode/treat-warnings-as-errors.html). This can help you solving nasty things that can happen latter in development.